# Question about limits of Facebook's data use policy

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm building a web app that will make heavy use of Facebook connect. I'm not planning on displaying publicly any data I receive from Facebook other than basic profile information. However, I would like give users the ability to display publicly to the world information such as what college they attend. I understand I could retrieve this data from facebook but sharing it would violate their data use policy. My question is, if I have the user enter the information manually into my application and I displayed it publicly, would facebook terminate my application?

My other question is I'm planning on creating an messaging feature in my application where users can message each other privately. Would this be a violation of facebook's policy since it might be interpreted as replicating facebook's messaging feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Retrieving and showing information doesn't violate their TOS. (But you need keep in mind items: II.3 and II.11 especially, as well as other items from http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)
2. You can implement on your site any feature you want

Comment: that applies for basic profile information correct? I can't take private facebook data and put it up for the world to see in my application.

Comment: @Casey Flynn: uhm, can you refer to particular TOS item that forbids that?